# Do I need load balancer if my Azure Website's autoscale is enabled?

Tags: azure

I have one Website on Azure:

1. I use Standard tier so the autoscale is on. Do I need to set the metric by myself or there are defaults? For example: when the CPU is above 90%, a new instance will be turned on. Do I have to add this by myself?
2. I saw there are options for "Data In" and "Data Out". Can I use this as a load balancer so that I don't need to configure a separate load balancer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having your website in the Standard tier doesn't mean autoscale is configured.  You still need to enable autoscale and configure the CPU target range for Azure to scale up/down the number of running instances.

Azure will load-balance requests to your running instances automatically so there is no need for you to "configure a separate load balancer".

The documentation on [how to scale websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/) covers this topic in depth.  It also shows you how to scale based on schedules if you have a need for that.

Comment: Thanks! What is the major reason to scale down? To save money? :) If money is not a big issue, can I just keep max instances?

Comment: One more question, I have a SQL database linked to it and I can config SQL scaling in the "Linked Resources" section. How do these two work? Is there any difference if I don't link them in the "Linked Resources"? The Azure portal just simply brings me to the SQL database "scale" section. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't care about costs then you can just increase your instance count without configuring autoscale.  As for the SQL Database, you can still scale it as needed even if it's not linked.